# Split a polygon into smaller polygons by containing 100 points each

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry, cluster-computing

At the moment I am trying to figure out a nice way to split up a polygon that has multiple points inside (in some cases more than 10k) into smaller ones that will have 100 points each (the max number of points within a small polygon will be dynamic, provided by the user, in this example I am using 100).
Please note that the 100 is not written in stone but should be respected (ex 95-105 points should be ok as when we try to balance things, sometimes we can not achieve perfect balance!)

Is there any algorithm that could help me achieve the above request?

The language I am using is javascript and so far I've been using turf.js and my data is in geoJSON format.

I am adding an image to highlight my goal:

In the image you can see that I already have a centroid point of my polygon (I used this point to make a voronoi diagram already and inside this polygon I have multiple point-features.
My goal is to split this polygon to smaller polygons that will hold only 100 points inside them.
(hope that clarifies my goal further)
[image]

Comment: You can check triangulation algorithms, maybe some of them can be extended to have more then 3 points. There are also Dirichlet tessellations, commonly known as Voronoi Polygons maybe you can do something with them.

Comment: thank you for your comment, not sure this is what I am after 100%.
I've updated the question and added an image to highlight what I would like to achieve.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your question what you're looking for is convex hull algorithm, there are known algorithms for that. Not exactly as your screenshot, it calculate polygon where points are your points only the most outer points are used on polygon.